# "Python.exe" crashes when PyQt's setPixmap() is called with a Pixmap

Tags: python, pyqt, qpixmap

I have a program that sends and receives images to each other using sockets.
The server sends the image data using 'image.tostring()' and the client side receives it and turns it back into an image using 'Image.fromstring', then into a QImage using 'ImageQt.ImageQt(image)', turns it into a QPixmap using 'QPixmap.fromimage(qimage)'then updates my QWidget's QLable's image using 'lable.setPixmap(qpixmap)'

Everything works fine with small images, but with images larger than 200x200, python.exe crashes and the console only shows "Process terminated with an exit code of -1073741819"  and doesn't tell me what the problem is.

I've isolated the problem down to 'setPixmap()' (everything else works as long as I comment out that), but I can't see what the problem is.

This only happens on the client side. The server side uses the same steps going from Image to QImage to QPixmap then setPixmap, but that doesn't have any problems.

Also tried making it a QBitmap and using setPixmap on the bitmap, which worked (but it's black and white so can't use it). Weird!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I am currently dealing with a very similar issue.

Comment: that is error 0xC0000005 (hex), [here](http://compfreakstars.blogspot.com/2011/11/0xc0000005-error-every-day-many.html) are some solutions

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth dumping the image data to a file and checking that you have all the data by loading it into an image viewer. If you get incomplete data, you may still be able to obtain a QImage and create a QPixmap, but it may be invalid.

Comment: In my case the QPixmap is fine. (If I write to a file, it's correct.) But Python still crashes when setPixmap is called.